# swift - update timer AND update lable after switch between controller

Tags: ios, swift, timer, label, countdown

my timer worked well even in Background-Mode ;-) I save the didEnterBG  tTime in Userdefaults and calculate the differenz in the WillEnterForeground.

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

My app start with an TABBAR-VC and than goes deeper via NAVIGATION-VC

Now if I start the timer and toggle between the TABBAR-VC the timerlable is updated well - BUT if I use the BACK Button from the NAVIGATION-VC and come back later the timerlable got the default time - no action for update, but the timer is still active (output from the debuger).

So what is missing - that the VC know that he has to update the lable again?

```
@objc func updateTimer() {

    if seconds == MY_TIME {
        print("savePoints")
        savePoints()

    }
    if seconds == 1 {
        self.playSound()
    }
    if seconds < 1 {
        clearTimer()
        saveAndReload()

        print("Aufgabe beendet")
        btPauseTimer.isEnabled = false
        btStopTimer.isEnabled = false
        btPauseTimer.setTitle("--", for: UIControlState.normal)
        btStopTimer.setTitle("--", for: UIControlState.normal)

    } else {
        seconds -= 1
        timerLabel.text = timeString(time: TimeInterval(seconds))
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it on my own ;-)

**I declare all VAR I need outside of my Controller.swift class (timer etc...)**
If the timer isRunning and I comeback to this VC - I call updateLabel() inside the viewAppears. This updateLabel method is another scheduled timer like the other obove, calling a method newString() with only this line every second ;-)

```
 timerLabel.text = timeString(time: TimeInterval(seconds))
```

---

**EDIT:**
This solution is the right way for me (I hope so.. ;-)

```
@objc func updateLabel(){
    if isBasicTimerRunning{
        timerLabel!.text = timeString(time: TimeInterval(secondsBasic))
        perform(#selector(updateLabel), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.01)

    }else{
    NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self)
    }

}
```

perform#selector tick the same method as long my timer is running - if not than the tick is canceled.

Comment: OK  - my answer was wrong!!!! If I do it in this way my timer works absolutely crazy - he runs, yes.... but afer count to 0 he starts again and again... OMG